# XSLT to convert dynamic XML to CSV and the XML nodes are not completely repetative

Tags: csv, xslt

Am trying to create an XSLT to convert XML to CSV. While searching I found so many examples but I didn't find any example related to dynamic XML nodes which are not repeating. Here am placing my XML and expected output anyone have any idea how to get the below output please share me.

My XML is

```
<SttlmOblgtnRpt>
    <RptParams>
        <RptId>02</RptId>
        <RptDtAndTm>
            <DtTm>2016-12-12T00:00:00</DtTm>
        </RptDtAndTm>
    </RptParams>
    <Pgntn>
        <PgNb>11</PgNb>
        <LastPgInd>true</LastPgInd>
    </Pgntn>
    <ClrMmb>
        <PrtryId>
            <Id>210016</Id>
            <Issr>MEMBER</Issr>
        </PrtryId>
    </ClrMmb>
</SttlmOblgtnRpt>
```

And my expected output is

RptId,DtTm,PgNb,LastPgInd,Id,Issr

02,2016-12-12T00:00:00,1,true,210016,MEMBER

Thanks,
Mahesh.

Comment: you basically want to output every text node. do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not entirely clear. It sounds like you want output a single row of data, with a cell for every leaf node:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="data" select="//*[not(*)]" />
    <!-- header -->
    <xsl:for-each select="$data">
        <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <!-- data -->
    <xsl:for-each select="$data">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, the result will be:

```
RptId,DtTm,PgNb,LastPgInd,Id,Issr
02,2016-12-12T00:00:00,11,true,210016,MEMBER
```

Comment: Thanks Michael ...  It works fine. Actually am completely new to XSLT. I have an XML file with different nodes and internally it have sub nodes and again in internal nodes contains sub nodes so by that time am not able to get the proper output in csv format. I have posted the same question with proper input/output in the following link please have a look and share me the XSLT logic. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42534968/xslt-to-convert-dynamic-xml-to-csv-and-the-xml-nodes-are-not-completely-repetati