# XSLT to convert dynamic XML to CSV and the XML nodes are not completely repetative II

Tags: csv, xslt

Am trying to create an XSLT to convert XML to CSV. Here am placing my XML and expected output anyone have any idea how to get the below output please share me on priority.

My XML is

```
  <SttlmOblgtnRpt>
<RptDtls>
  <SttlmOblgtnDtls>
    <SttlmOblgtnId>A</SttlmOblgtnId>
    <FinInstrmId>
      <OthrId>
        <Id>SETTLE</Id>
        <Tp>
          <Cd>CO</Cd>
        </Tp>
      </OthrId>
    </FinInstrmId>
    <IntnddSttlmDt>
      <Dt>
        <Dt>2011-11-11</Dt>
      </Dt>
    </IntnddSttlmDt>
    <Qty>
      <Unit>11</Unit>
    </Qty>
    <SttlmAmt>
      <Amt Ccy="ZAR">20.00</Amt>
    </SttlmAmt>
    <PlcOfTrad>
      <Id>
        <Desc>SA</Desc>
      </Id>
      <Tp>
        <Cd>PR</Cd>
      </Tp>
    </PlcOfTrad>
    <Pmt>Fail</Pmt>
    <AddtlSttlmOblgtnDtls>
      <RltdSttlmOblgtnId>Debit</RltdSttlmOblgtnId>
      <Qty>
        <Unit>200</Unit>
      </Qty>
      <SttlmAmt>
        <Amt Ccy="ZAR">22.00</Amt>
      </SttlmAmt>
      <SttlmDt>2011-11-11</SttlmDt>
      <SctiesMvmntTp>INDIA</SctiesMvmntTp>
      <Pmt>MT</Pmt>
    </AddtlSttlmOblgtnDtls>
    <AddtlSttlmOblgtnDtls>
      <RltdSttlmOblgtnId>Outward</RltdSttlmOblgtnId>
      <Qty>
        <Unit>1</Unit>
      </Qty>
      <SttlmAmt>
        <Amt Ccy="ZAR">100.00</Amt>
      </SttlmAmt>
      <SttlmDt>2015-12-01</SttlmDt>
      <SctiesMvmntTp>UK</SctiesMvmntTp>
      <Pmt>EMP</Pmt>
    </AddtlSttlmOblgtnDtls>
  </SttlmOblgtnDtls>
</RptDtls>
<RptDtls>
  <SttlmOblgtnDtls>
    <SttlmOblgtnId>B</SttlmOblgtnId>
    <FinInstrmId>
      <OthrId>
        <Id>UNSETTLE</Id>
        <Tp>
          <Cd>MM</Cd>
        </Tp>
      </OthrId>
    </FinInstrmId>
    <IntnddSttlmDt>
      <Dt>
        <Dt>2012-12-12</Dt>
      </Dt>
    </IntnddSttlmDt>
    <Qty>
      <Unit>22</Unit>
    </Qty>
    <SttlmAmt>
      <Amt Ccy="ZAR">60.00</Amt>
    </SttlmAmt>
    <PlcOfTrad>
      <Id>
        <Desc>RB</Desc>
      </Id>
      <Tp>
        <Cd>IM</Cd>
      </Tp>
    </PlcOfTrad>
    <Pmt>Ok</Pmt>
    <AddtlSttlmOblgtnDtls>
      <RltdSttlmOblgtnId>Credit</RltdSttlmOblgtnId>
      <Qty>
        <Unit>100</Unit>
      </Qty>
      <SttlmAmt>
        <Amt Ccy="ZAR">66.00</Amt>
      </SttlmAmt>
      <SttlmDt>2012-12-12</SttlmDt>
      <SctiesMvmntTp>DELHI</SctiesMvmntTp>
      <Pmt>AP</Pmt>
    </AddtlSttlmOblgtnDtls>
    <AddtlSttlmOblgtnDtls>
      <RltdSttlmOblgtnId>Value</RltdSttlmOblgtnId>
      <Qty>
        <Unit>111</Unit>
      </Qty>
      <SttlmAmt>
        <Amt Ccy="ZAR">666.00</Amt>
      </SttlmAmt>
      <SttlmDt>2001-05-05</SttlmDt>
      <SctiesMvmntTp>US</SctiesMvmntTp>
      <Pmt>PASS</Pmt>
    </AddtlSttlmOblgtnDtls>
  </SttlmOblgtnDtls>
 </RptDtls>  </SttlmOblgtnRpt>
```

And my expected output is

SttlmOblgtnId,Pmt,Id,Cd,Dt,Unit,Amt,Desc,Cd,RltdSttlmOblgtnId,SttlmDt,SctiesMvmntTp,Pmt,Unit,Amt

A,Fail,SETTLE,CO,11/11/2011,11,20,SA,PR,Debit,11/11/2011,INDIA,MT,200,22

,,,,,,,,,Outward,12/1/2015,UK,EMP,1,100

B,Ok,UNSETTLE,MM,12/12/2012,22,60,RB,IM,Credit,12/12/2012,DELHI,AP,100,66

,,,,,,,,,Value,5/5/2001,US,PASS,111,666

Thanks,

Mahesh.

Comment: The example is not really telling us much. Please explain the **logic** that needs to applied in order to get the expected output.

Comment: All the column names in one line with comma separated like col1,col2,col3, ----- like that and in below line the respective column values should be print like value1,value2,value3,----. If the particular column don't have value then need to print space like for example if col2 don't have value then the output like value1,,value3,----. Hope now you understood if not please reply me

Comment: The thing I don't understand is how do you pick the columns. Do you have a hard-coded list of elements to look at? If yes, this should be fairly easy.

Comment: There is no hard-coded list of elements. In the given answer stylesheet the elements are hard-coded but I want it to be dynamically because every time the elements(names) are changing. And in the given answer stylesheet am not getting Unit element value which is under AddtlSttlmOblgtnDtls/Qty/Unit in this place am getting Amt value instead of Unit element value. And other one my actual XML has 6 sections related to AddtlSttlmOblgtnDtls under one RptDtls section. In the given answer you have wrote logic like <!-- first row -->,<!-- second row --> but I want this logic in loop. Thanks Michael

Comment: I don't see how it's possible to arrive at the expected output "dynamically". Some of the leaf nodes appear in the output, and some don't. And the order of those that do appear is not the document order.

Comment: can you please share me the for each loop for below  <!-- first AddtlSttlmOblgtnDtls -->  <!-- second row --> because I have total 7 AddtlSttlmOblgtnDtls  nodes

Comment: I am not sure what would be the point of that, if the basic approach is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
<xsl:template match="RptDtls">
    <xsl:for-each select="descendant::AddtlSttlmOblgtnDtls">
        <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="parent::SttlmOblgtnDtls/SttlmOblgtnId[$pos]"/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="parent::SttlmOblgtnDtls/Pmt[$pos]"/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="parent::SttlmOblgtnDtls/FinInstrmId[$pos]/OthrId/Id"/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="parent::SttlmOblgtnDtls/FinInstrmId[$pos]/OthrId/Tp/Cd"/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="replace(parent::SttlmOblgtnDtls/IntnddSttlmDt[$pos]/Dt/Dt, '([\d]{4})-0?([\d]{1,2})-0?([\d]{1,2})', '$2/$3/$1')"/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="parent::SttlmOblgtnDtls/Qty[$pos]/Unit"/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:if test="normalize-space(parent::SttlmOblgtnDtls/SttlmAmt[$pos]/Amt) !=''">
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(parent::SttlmOblgtnDtls/SttlmAmt[$pos]/Amt, '0')"/>
        </xsl:if><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="parent::SttlmOblgtnDtls/PlcOfTrad[$pos]/Id/Desc"/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="parent::SttlmOblgtnDtls/PlcOfTrad[$pos]/Tp/Cd"/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="RltdSttlmOblgtnId"/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="replace(SttlmDt, '([\d]{4})-0?([\d]{1,2})-0?([\d]{1,2})', '$2/$3/$1')"/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="SctiesMvmntTp"/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="Pmt"/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="Qty/Unit"/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(SttlmAmt/Amt, '0')"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

**Output is**

```
A,Fail,SETTLE,CO,11/11/2011,11,20,SA,PR,Debit,11/11/2011,INDIA,MT,200,22
,,,,,,,,,Outward,12/1/2015,UK,EMP,1,100
B,Ok,UNSETTLE,MM,12/12/2012,22,60,RB,IM,Credit,12/12/2012,DELHI,AP,100,66
,,,,,,,,,Value,5/5/2001,US,PASS,111,666
```

Comment: am not getting out put am getting output as <?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?> .........

Answer (score 0):

The following stylesheet will produce the expected result (minus some formatting issues) from the given example. Whether that's the logic you want to apply in general is not clear.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />

<xsl:template match="/SttlmOblgtnRpt">
    <!-- header -->
    <xsl:text>SttlmOblgtnId,Pmt,Id,Cd,Dt,Unit,Amt,Desc,Cd,RltdSttlmOblgtnId,SttlmDt,SctiesMvmntTp,Pmt,Unit,Amt&#10;</xsl:text>
    <!-- data -->
    <xsl:for-each select="RptDtls/SttlmOblgtnDtls">
        <!-- first row -->
        <xsl:value-of select="SttlmOblgtnId" />
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="Pmt" />
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="FinInstrmId/OthrId/Id" />
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="FinInstrmId/OthrId/Tp/Cd" />
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="IntnddSttlmDt/Dt/Dt" />
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="Qty/Unit" />
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="SttlmAmt/Amt" />
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="PlcOfTrad/Id/Desc" />
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="PlcOfTrad/Tp/Cd" />
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <!-- first AddtlSttlmOblgtnDtls -->
        <xsl:value-of select="AddtlSttlmOblgtnDtls[1]/RltdSttlmOblgtnId" />
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="AddtlSttlmOblgtnDtls[1]/SttlmDt" />
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="AddtlSttlmOblgtnDtls[1]/SctiesMvmntTp" />
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="AddtlSttlmOblgtnDtls[1]/Pmt" />
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="AddtlSttlmOblgtnDtls[1]/SttlmAmt/Amt" />
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        <!-- second row -->
        <xsl:text>,,,,,,,,,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="AddtlSttlmOblgtnDtls[2]/RltdSttlmOblgtnId" />
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="AddtlSttlmOblgtnDtls[2]/SttlmDt" />
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="AddtlSttlmOblgtnDtls[2]/SctiesMvmntTp" />
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="AddtlSttlmOblgtnDtls[2]/Pmt" />
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="AddtlSttlmOblgtnDtls[2]/SttlmAmt/Amt" />
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```
SttlmOblgtnId,Pmt,Id,Cd,Dt,Unit,Amt,Desc,Cd,RltdSttlmOblgtnId,SttlmDt,SctiesMvmntTp,Pmt,Unit,Amt
A,Fail,SETTLE,CO,2011-11-11,11,20.00,SA,PR,Debit,2011-11-11,INDIA,MT,22.00
,,,,,,,,,Outward,2015-12-01,UK,EMP,100.00
B,Ok,UNSETTLE,MM,2012-12-12,22,60.00,RB,IM,Credit,2012-12-12,DELHI,AP,66.00
,,,,,,,,,Value,2001-05-05,US,PASS,666.00
```