# Combining records based on multiple values of multiple tags using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have a confusion over one of my files that I have been trying to 
create using **XSLT.**

I want an output of this type:

```
EmpID|Languages|LanguageAbility|LanguagePro|Certificate-Issuer|Certification|Certificate-ID
```

```
000626390|English|Overall||C1|C2|

000626390|Turkish|Overall||||
```

XML: This is a sample XML for my code

```
    <wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/Languages">
                <wd:Report_Entry>
                    <wd:EmpID>000626390</wd:EmpID>
                    <wd:Languages>
                        <wd:Languages>English</wd:Languages>
                        <wd:LanguageAbility>Overall</wd:LanguageAbility>
                    </wd:Languages>
                    <wd:Languages>
                        <wd:Languages>Turkish</wd:Languages>
                        <wd:LanguageAbility>Overall</wd:LanguageAbility>
                    </wd:Languages>
                    <wd:Certifications>               
                        <wd:Certificate-Issuer>C1</wd:Certificate-Issuer>
                        <wd:Certification>C2</wd:Certification>
                    </wd:Certifications>
                </wd:Report_Entry>
            </wd:Report_Data>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [xslt-to-convert-dynamic-xml-to-csv-and-the-xml-nodes-are-not-completely-repetati](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42534968/xslt-to-convert-dynamic-xml-to-csv-and-the-xml-nodes-are-not-completely-repetati/42536209#42536209)

Answer (score 0):

As your sample xml doesn't contain any LanguagePro and Certficate-ID so we assume that it is sibling of Language,

**XSLT 2.0**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/Languages"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="wd:Report_Entry">
        <xsl:for-each select="wd:Languages">
            <xsl:variable name="position" select="position()"/>
            <xsl:if test="position() != 1"><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text></xsl:if>
            <xsl:value-of select="parent::wd:Report_Entry/wd:EmpID
                |wd:Languages
                |wd:LanguageAbility
                " separator="|"></xsl:value-of>
            <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="parent::wd:Report_Entry/LanguagePro"/>
            <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="parent::wd:Report_Entry/wd:Certifications[$position]/wd:Certificate-Issuer"/>
            <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="parent::wd:Report_Entry/wd:Certifications[$position]/wd:Certification"/>
            <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="parent::wd:Report_Entry/Certificate-ID"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```